# CSR, and SSL certificate. and Private Key

Tags: ssl, private-key, public-key, csr

I created CSR using my key pair. and I believe that CSR will only include my Public Key. and I sent the CSR to CA. and I got certificate from the CA.
When I look at certificate. I can see that it has **serial number** and some identity information.

Lets say, I create JWS(JSON Web Signature) of this **serial number** and identity information with my private key, and send it to CA.
How do they decrypt (or validate) it? (Because I don't believe that they have my private key.)

Comment: The CSR _contains_ your publickey _and_ identity (specifically, Subject Distinguished Name), may contain some other fields [(see RFC2986)](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2986), and is signed by your privatekey, which like all digital signatures the CA verifies using the publickey, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography . This signature does not use JWS format (it uses ASN.1, and was defined long before JOSE was invented), and there is no encryption. The serial number is assigned by the CA; you don't send it. This is not a programming or development issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah I know that usually you don't send certificate. But, this particular api required me to send JWS in http header which was generated using serial no. and my private key. I was wondered how they validate my request.

Answer (score 0):

Oh.. I see, When I send JWS with my private key. I don't use that key for encryption. I use my private key to sign the message.

then CA will know that I signed by my private key. because they have public key. and Serial Number is not actually encrypted in JWS but signed by me.

> The contents of JWS token are Base64 encoded and not encrypted
> (remember encoding is different from encryption!).

Comment: You don't send JWS to the CA. The CA signs your certificate once, then they're no longer directly involved in subsequent transactions (however relying parties may query the CA to verify that your certificate hasn't been revoked).

Comment: Yes, you are right. but my particular case, I had to send JWS to third party api. I was wondering what going on when I send it. Thanks @President J